# I got Google Drive Api: parse error with post request

Tags: parsing, google-drive-api

I want to share a google drive file. I do post request to [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileid]/permissions](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%5Bfileid%5D/permissions)
header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]'
header 'Accept: application/json'
header 'Content-Type: application/json'
with body "{
"role": "reader",
"type": "anyone"
}". But I got "code": 400,
"message": "Parse Error". Where is the problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. You seem to be fetching/providing the right URL, headers, and request body. The only I can think of, with the provided information, is that you're using `"` for each key/value in the request body and also for enclosing the full body. Can you make the enclosing quotes single and see if the problem is fixed? Something like `'{"role":"reader","type":"anyone"}'`.

Comment: Hi! Did the fix I suggested in my comment solve your issue? If that's the case, I'd post this as an answer.